# QuickBooks Add Customer with our customer id

Tags: .net, quickbooks

I am using webconnector to add a customer to QuickBooks from my application, below is the XML i am currently generating and passing to quickbooks which is working fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
<CustomerAddRq requestID="1">
<CustomerAdd>
<Name>xx test1</Name>
<FirstName>xx</FirstName>
<LastName>test1</LastName>
<BillAddress>
<Addr1>xx test1</Addr1>
<Addr2>1115 Massachusetts Avenue </Addr2>
<City>Lexington</City>
<State>MA</State>
<PostalCode>02420</PostalCode>
</BillAddress>
<ShipAddress>
<Addr1>xx tester</Addr1>
<Addr2>1115 Massachusetts Avenue </Addr2>
<City>Lexington</City>
<State>MA</State>
<PostalCode>02420</PostalCode>
</ShipAddress>
<Phone>1111111111</Phone>
<AltPhone/>
<Email>xx@gmail.com</Email>
<Contact>xx tester</Contact>
<CustomerTypeRef>
<FullName>RETAIL</FullName>
</CustomerTypeRef>
<SalesTaxCodeRef>
<FullName>Non</FullName>
</SalesTaxCodeRef>
<ItemSalesTaxRef>
<FullName>Out of State</FullName>
</ItemSalesTaxRef>
</CustomerAdd>
</CustomerAddRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The customer data is generated from a different source and fed in Quick Books, I need to pass the customer ID also to Quick Books and then later add a sales receipt for this customer referencing the Customer ID.

1. How do i add my customer id to CustomerAddRq?
2. How do i add my customer id to SalesReceiptAddRq to reference the sale for this customer?

Regards,
Javeed

Answer (score 0):

> How do i add my customer id to CustomerAddRq?

Put the value in the XML tag corresponding to the field you want to store the data in.

Don't know what XML tag to put it in? Refer to the documentation:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

> How do i add my customer id to SalesReceiptAddRq to reference the sale for this customer?

This is the same question as above... put your value in whatever XML tag you want to store data in.